# How do you unlock Quan Chi?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

How do you unlock Quan Chi in Mortal Kombat 9 without doing the story mode and beating a certain chapter?

Answer (score 1):

Well you unlock him by beating the story mode, so to unlock him without playing the story mode would require modding or scripting of some sorts.